# Facebook & Android - GraphAPI or FQL?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk

If I want to display the user his news feed \ profile etc in a mobile android app,

What should I use to acquire the data?

GraphAPI or FQL?

Is there any data that is available in one of the methods but not in the other?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data using the FB Android SDK, https://developers.facebook.com/android/

Then make FQL or Graph API calls:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/run-fql-queries/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request

You may find it easier to access some data via one method or the other.  Check the fql tables and use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to inspect the data that is available.

FQL Tables:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/toc/